# How to read text file from Firebase storage in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, file, text, firebase-storage

I am uploading text files in Firebase storage and storing some data in Firebase real-time database.
No problem in doing the above thing.

Also, I am able to fetch all the files present in firestorage along with the URL of text file.
**But I am not able to read the content inside a text file.**

I am using below code to fetch the data

I am calling getfileDetails() method in init to store all data in fileDetailList before calling below code

```
 this.uploadService.fileDetailList.snapshotChanges().subscribe(
      list => {
        console.log("before fileListDetails= ");
        this.fileListDetails = list.map((item) => {
          return item.payload.val();
        });
        console.log("fileListDetails= " + JSON.stringify(this.fileListDetails)); //logs attached below
        this.FileDetailsList = this.fileListDetails;

        this.FileDetailsList.forEach((item) => {
          console.log("item= " + item.imgUrl);
        
           // to get the text from file
          this.http.get<string>(item.imgUrl).subscribe(
            (item11)=>{

              console.log("file read= "+item11); //getting error Here
              
            }
          );
        });
      }
    );
```

my uploadService.ts  method

```
fileDetailList:AngularFireList<any>;

constructor(private firebase:AngularFireDatabase) { }

  getfileDetails()
  {
    console.log("getfileDetails");
    this.fileDetailList=this.firebase.list('FileDetails');
  }
```

logs Details

```
fileListDetails= [{"caption":"nkn,","category":"hello.txt","imgUrl":"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/...."}]
```

when I am hitting imgUrl in the browser directly I am able to get the text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell the http client that you expect a plain text response rather than the default which is JSON

Note that when specifying a `responseType` other than JSON you do not need to need to give a generic argument like `this.http.get<MyType>` as it is already specified.

```
this.http.get(item.imgUrl, {responseType: "text"}).subscribe(...)
```

Ref:
https://angular.io/guide/http#requesting-data-from-a-server

Comment: But i was telling that return will be string  http.get<string>

Comment: The generic `<string>` is a hint to typescript that the response will be a string but unfortunately this type information is not available at runtime, which is why you also need to specify how to parse the response with the `responseType`

Comment: Thanks Michael it works for me but after removing string from start now my http call looks like this http.get(url,{responseType:"text})

Comment: It's better to keep the generic `<string>` on the start, as otherwise your response will probably be of type `any` which is dangerous. (Unless the method signature is constraining the generic to make it redundant)

Comment: Getting error while keeping the starting string >> type "text" is not assignable to type ' "json" '      The expected type comes from property 'responseType' which is declared here on type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe: "events"; params?: HttpParams | { [param: string]: string | string[]; }; reportProgress?: boolean; responseType?: "json"; withCredentials?: boolean; }'
http.d.ts(1061, 9):

Comment: Ah ok, yeah it's been constrained by the method overloads and should be removed. I'll update my answer to clarify this when I get home